# Reading from a file and copying it's contents through command line

Tags: c++

I want to read a file and copy it's contents to all the files that are passed as command line arguments
for example:

> main.exe file.txt todo.txt app.txt foo.txt

Read data from file1 and copy it's contens to todo, app and foo. Prompt the user if the file doesn't exist and ask for input if he wants to create file.

The ReadFile function works and returns the file data.

code:

```
char* ReadFile(const char* filename) {...}

void WriteFile(const char* filename, const char* data) {
    FILE* fptr = fopen(filename, "r+");
    if (fptr)
        std::cout << filename << " opened Succesfully.\n";
    else {
        std::cout << "\nFile not found! Do you want to create one?\n";
        std::cout << "Type Y, y or 1 to create the file that doesn't exist press any other key to exit\n";
        std::string input;
        std::cin >> input;
        while (input.at(0) == 'Y' || input.at(0) == 'y' || input.at(0) == '1') {
            fptr = fopen(filename, "w");
            if (fptr) {
                std::cout << filename << " created Succesfully\n";
                break;
            } else {
                std::cout << "Error creating " << filename << std::endl;
                break;
            }
        }
        while (input.at(0) != 'Y' || input.at(0) != 'y' || input.at(0) != '1') {    
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    while ((*data)) {
        fputc(*data, fptr);
        ++data;
    }
    if (!fclose(fptr))
        std::cout << filename << " closed\n";
    else 
        std::cout << "Error closing " << filename << std::endl;

}
int main(int argv, const char* argc[]) {
    const char* FileBuffer = ReadFile(argc[1]);
   
    for (int i = 2; i < 10; ++i) {
        if (argc[i] != (char)0 )
            WriteFile(argc[i], FileBuffer);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now the problem is whenever I create a file that doesn't exist it prints: "File created Successfully" and exits but the contents are never copied

second: I cannot write to a file with more than 2 arguments **that doesn't exists** example :

> main.exe file.txt todo.txt app.txt foo.txt

Here file.txt is read successfully, then it asks me whether I want to create a file, I input "y" it prints "File created successfully" and exits but the contents are never copied

however If the files exists the code works fine and the contents are copied to all the files

Note: I am not using fstream because I'm having issues for reading and writing

Comment: I don't think you meant to use those 'while' loops to check for 'Yy1'. Or at least not in this way. You don't modify 'input' in those loops.

Comment: @Patrick So what do I do?

Comment: I'm fairly certain those should be 'if' statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
while (input.at(0) != 'Y' || input.at(0) != 'y' || input.at(0) != '1')
```

is always true so your program always exits, you meant to write

```
while (input.at(0) != 'Y' && input.at(0) != 'y' && input.at(0) != '1')
```

It's a common error to get the logic wrong when combining negation with `and` or `or`.

And since the body of the while loop always exits the program, it a little clearer to write an `if` statement instead of a `while` statement.

```
if (input.at(0) != 'Y' && input.at(0) != 'y' && input.at(0) != '1')
    exit(0);
```

Comment: the `while` above also should be an `if` or different

Comment: @idclev463035818 That's true, both loops should be combined into one `if else` statement.